# Using the correct amount of URLs that are given in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, pickle

I am trying to setup a python script that uses URLs. I already have a relatively simple script that asks for and saves the URLs to a file using the Pickle library, you can see the code for that below. FYI I did not do the following code, another user helped me figure out how to do this.

```
import os
import pickle
urlnum = int(input("How many urls? "))
urllist = []

for e in range(urlnum):
    urllist.append(input("Type URL %s " % str(e+1)))
os.system("cls")
print("Your URLs are the following")
print(" ")
print(urllist)
print(" ")
print(" ")
pickle.dump(urllist, open("urllist.dat", "wb"))
print("Your list is done saving. Press enter to continue.")
input(" ")
```

And I have two different ideas of how to use the URLs.
One is to have a Python script that uses the URLs in the way that i want them, or somehow compile them all into one python script that either changes the URL variable to the one its using each time, or save all of the URLs as different variables and have them all use there own URL variable.

So what I need is a python script that gets the amount of items in a given array and use the URLs in the array to do what I need them to do. I'm not sure if I need to define the command and have it change based on the amount of times its run, so as if x is the amount of items in the array, and it runs and changes the script/command x amount of times.

I'm not the greatest with coding, so I would love to hear your suggestions and what you would recommend i do and what libraries i should and shouldn't use and what i should change.

The library that im using that needs the urls is called dhooks, its a discord webhook library, and to import it i use `from dhooks import Webhook`
and the code is kind of like this.

```
from dhooks import Webhook
hook = Webhook('url')
hook.send("message here")
```

and to send it to multiple URLs what i did before was the following.

```
from dhooks import Webhook
url1 = 'firstURL'
url2 = 'secondURL'
hook = Webhook(url1)
hook.send("message here")
hook = Webhook(url2)
hook.send("message here")
```

Its not the best as if i want to have more webhooks then i need to edit the code myself to have the proper amount of URLs.

Documentation for the library can be found here https://pypi.org/project/dhooks/

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you are trying to do. What are you trying to do with the URLs? Save them to a file and retrieve them? Or run a function on each URL?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 im technically not doing this for just me. Me and my friend want to have a Python script that sends updates through webhooks to multiple server and i decided i wanted to code it, so what i'm trying to do is to have the same script run on each webhook. I hope this makes sense, if it doesn't, please let me know what is confusing. Thank you.

Comment: What does this other script look like? You could loop over the url list and run your script for each url.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 I edited it to hopefully clarify better and give more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a message for each url in the file you could use a for loop:

```
from dhooks import Webhook
import pickle

urllist = pickle.load( open( "urllist.dat", "rb" ) )

for url in urllist:
  hook = Webhook(url)
  hook.send("message here")
```

Comment: I think this would work, however, i'm not sure how i would get the different urls for each one, like using the percentage sign in the script of getting the user input for the URLs. I dont know how the percent sign works in python, if you are able to, please explain this to me. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the script above is getting the urls from the file and sending a message for each url (so each of the different urls). The percent sign just formats the string with another value inside. You can read more about it here: https://pyformat.info/. Basically, having "Bob " + "ate" + " pie" is the same as "Bob %s pie" % "ate" is the same as "Bob ate pie"